# Two resources for one route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm learning rails and downloaded some rails project (rails 3.2.6), it has such entries in routes.rb:

```
require 'logged_in_constraint'

VkontakteOnRails::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'callback'  => 'sessions#callback'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

  root to: 'main#index', constraints: LoggedInConstraint.new
  root to: 'sessions#new'
end
```

It is straightforward that based on that user is Logged in or not root route leads to different controllers. Am I right? 
But if i change rails version in project to 4.2.1 I get error on server start:

```
Exiting
/Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:555:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'  (ArgumentError)
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1561:in `add_route'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1536:in `decomposed_match'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1517:in `block in match'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1507:in `each'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1507:in `match'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:387:in `root'
    from /Users/khataev/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1580:in `root'
    from /Users/khataev/Documents/development/rails/vkontakte_on_rails/config/routes.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
....
```

Does it mean that new rails don't support this feature anymore?

Comment: You can't provide the root twice even if you have the constraints there the the second root would always apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `as:` option to the second root route:

```
VkontakteOnRails::Application.routes.draw do
  # some code here
  root to: 'main#index', constraints: LoggedInConstraint.new
  root to: 'sessions#new', as: :unauth
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one `root` per application. If it not included in `namespace`

```
root to: "home#index"

namespace :admin do
  root to: "admin#index"
end
```

Comment: So, why it was possible in rails 3.2.6?